# Get list with condition on sub list

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have two list listA is a list of `MyClassA` and listB of `MyClassB`

`MyClassA` with properties :

- Id
- Name

`MyClassB` with properties :

- Id
- Name
- Active
- MyClassAId

An item `MyClassA` can have one or more item MyClassB

```
- MyClassA
    |
    | MyClassB
    | MyClassB
- MyClassA
    |
    | MyClassB
    | MyClassB
    | MyClassB
    | MyClassB
```

I'd like get a list of `MyClassA` where the number of items `MyClassB` with `active = true` is > 1

I tried something like this :

```
listA.Where(b => listB.Any(a => a.MyClassAId == b.Id && a.Active == true));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Any` will be > 0. For > 1 you could do something like:

```
listA.Where(a => listB.Count(b => b.MyClassAId == a.Id && b.Active) > 1);
```

or with better short-circuiting (but probabably fine for LINQ-to-Objects, but not EF etc):

```
listA.Where(
    a => listB.Where(b => b.MyClassAId == a.Id && b.Active).Skip(1).Any());
```

Another approach would be to pre-compute the counts:

```
var include = new HashSet<int>(listB.Where(b => b.Active)
                  .GroupBy(b => b.MyClassAId)
                  .Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1)
                  .Select(grp => grp.Key));
```

Then:

```
listA.Where(a => include.Contains(a.Id));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = (from a in listA let count = listB.Count(b => b.Active && a.Id == b.MyClassAId) where count > 1 select a).ToList();
```