# Get object from a sub list c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am having hard time doing something like this question:
[Get list from a sublist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507490/get-list-with-condition-on-sub-list)

Consider

```
Class Menu
{
    int Id;
    string Name;
    bool IsActive;
    List<Menu> SubMenus;
}

List<Menu> someList;
```

I want to get one of the item from the `someList.SubMenus` based on id, and update its `Name` property.

What I have done uptill now:

`var objectToUpdate = viewModel.menuSubMenuTreeList.Where(x => x.SubMenus.Where(y => y.MenuID == subMenuId).Any()).FirstOrDefault();`

It doesn't seem to work. Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for something like `viewModel.menuSubMenuTreeList.Select(x => x.SubMenus).Where(y => y.MenuID == subMenuId).FirstOrDefault()`?

Comment: No that didn't work. `y.MenuID` is not avaialble. `y` itself is a list in the `where` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have filtered the parent item based on condition. Only thing you are missing is getting the child item:

C# 7:

```
var objectToUpdate = viewModel.menuSubMenuTreeList
                     .Where(x => x.SubMenus.Where(y => y.MenuID == subMenuId).Any())
                     .FirstOrDefault()?.SubMenus.Where(y => y.MenuID == subMenuId);
```

Earlier version:

```
var found = viewModel.menuSubMenuTreeList
                     .Where(x => x.SubMenus.Where(y => y.MenuID == subMenuId).Any())
                     .FirstOrDefault();

var objectToUpdate = found != null ? found.SubMenus.Where(y => y.MenuID == subMenuId) : null;
```

Comment: +1 thanks that worked like a charm! But can you please explain this to me a little? I mean I can't understand the second time you looked for `SubMenus.Where....`

Comment: First time you got parent containing the object then you get the child from parent in second step.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all submenus into a single list using SelectMany:

```
var submenus = someList.SelectMany( x => x.SubMenus );
```

From there you can find the submenu:

```
var submenu = submenus.Where( x => x.Id == subMenuId );
```

And set its Name:

```
submenu.Name = "SomeName";
```

Put it all together:

```
someList
    .SelectMany
    ( 
        x => x.SubMenus 
    )
    .Where
    (
        x => x.Id == subMenuId
    )
    .Name = "SomeName";
```

Comment: While this solution also worked for me. But since Vendettamit responded earlier hence I have accepted his answer. I don't think in terms of performance any of them is bad. Everyone's input is appreciated. Thanks a lot John Wu.